# Is there a way to intercept Android SMS sending to forward to different transport?

Tags: android, sms, send, intercept

For example, can I listen for some broadcast from the app layer (e.g., messaging) and consume the message prior to the telephony layer sends it out of the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive an intent and process a message on receipt of a message, however there is nothing you can do to stop and outgoing text message. Many people want to be able to detect for sent messages, and that in itself can be difficult. The only way that that can be done is by reading the SMS ContentProvider, which isn't something that comes recommended by many.

Answer (score 1):

No. There are no broadcast intents for outgoing messages, only incoming.